# I got some issues in using Form.File react-bootstrap component

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I imported the component like this:

```
import { Form } from 'react-bootstrap'
<Form.File
   id='image-file'
   label='Choose File'
   custom
   onChange={uploadFileHandler}
   ></Form.File>
```

I got the following error:

`Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.`

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Your questions about code, i.e. debugging questions like these, are served by not only providing the code + error message, but also a textual description on what the code is supposed to do, and what it currently does, see [mcve]. Also showing what you have already tried to solve the problem is appreciated. Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such component called Form.File. You have to use Form.Control with type="file":

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/forms/form-control/#file-input